# Negative area of surface of revolution

Tags: calculus

Find the area of surface of revolution of $f(x)=-\frac{x^3}{21}$ rotated about the y-axis on the interval $[-2\sqrt{6}, 0]$.

Solution: $$S=\int_{a}^{b}2\pi x \sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2} dx$$
$$S=\int_{-2\sqrt{6}}^{0}2\pi x \sqrt{1+\left(-\frac{x^2}{7}\right)^2} dx$$

But this integral is negative.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify $$S=\int_{a}^{b}2\pi x \sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2} dx$$ to be 
$$S=\int_{a}^{b}2\pi |x| \sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2} dx$$

See for example section "3. Revolution About The y-axis" in [this document](http://www.phengkimving.com/calc_of_one_real_var/12_app_of_the_intgrl/12_07_areas_of_surf_of_revltn.htm). The $x$ that you have before the square root has a meaning of radius, so it must be positive.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you are using shell method. The 'more correct' form is actually
$$S=\int_{a}^{b}2\pi |x| \sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2} dx$$
because you don't want to have your shell with negative thickness ($\delta x$ being negative due to the limits).

Answer (score 1):

Invisible before every square root radial sign $\sqrt{...  }$ is a symbol $\pm$ that is "normally" taken positive in a commonly accepted *convention*.

Evaluated integrals follow this convention.. heavily influenced by positive lengths, angles and slopes.

In your situation the scalar surface area needs an interpretation.

You get *eight* possibilities of evaluting surface area by

- considering $x$ positive or negative
- considering interchanged limits of integration $ \int_{0} ^{ 2\sqrt 6}..$ in place of $ \int_{ 2\sqrt 6}^{0} ..$
- considering either sign in front of $\sec \phi = \sqrt{1+\tan^2 \phi} =\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2}$

Signs of geometrical quantities such as  length, surface area,volumes are not sacrosanct but need *contextual interpretation* depending on influencing factors like the three mentioned above.